# Cant install extension on Joomla 3.1

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla3.1

I am running joomla on IIS 7.5 and MSSQL, everything seems to be working just fine, but when I install JCE Eqitor from the admin panel it times out and when i check the logs for error this is what i got:

> PHP Notice:  Undefined index: cache_entries in
>   D:\Joomlawebsite\libraries\joomla\cache\storage\wincache.php on line
>   147
>
> PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   D:\Joomlawebsite\libraries\joomla\cache\storage\wincache.php on line
>   150

I have IUSR permission as well.

Comment: try going to your global configuration and turning the cache off

Comment: there isnt a single setting as off/on. there's a component called Cache Manger with bunch of settings.

Comment: ok found it under system and its already off.

Comment: its off and it doesnt work.

Comment: try disabling the cache manager component

Comment: In the Joomla Backend, go to:
`Extensions > Extension Manager`, find the name of it and unpublish it

Comment: hi checked, there's nothing as Cache manager component.

Comment: `there's a component called Cache Manger with bunch of settings.` << if it's a component then it will be in that list

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to completely uninstall extension

   http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/joomla-25/extensions/uninstall-extension

   also modules and plugins if extension have.
2. Try to clear your site cache.
3. Go to global configration and check your site all folder's has writable permission.
4. try to install again with jce installation doc.  http://www.joomlacontenteditor.net/support/installation/editor/item/install-or-update-the-jce-editor-in-joomla3